# Android Manifest file error after adding AdMob

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I have gone through the below link for integrating AdMob

http://fastegggames.com/blog/2013/3/30/tutorial-admob

and Follwing is the error when i tried to build my .apk to test AdMob :

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\android-sdk-windows1\build-tools\19.0.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/android-sdk-windows1/platforms/android-19\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages  -S "C:\Users\avisingh.TAGS\Desktop\ONE_07\ONE_07\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res"

stderr[
C:\Users\avisingh.TAGS\Desktop\ONE_07\ONE_07\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res\values\strings.xml: error: Duplicate file.
res\values\strings.xml: Original is here.
]
stdout[
Processing raw dir 'C:\Users\avisingh.TAGS\Desktop\ONE_07\ONE_07\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook\res'
]
```

I tried to build in API18 and API19 but still the same error. Can any one please help me through